# Forge Viewer closing, but data persists

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

In my project the user has the ability to open an model in a viewer and then click a button and close the viewer.  The viewer is being created by this:

```
function launchViewer(urn, name) {
    var options = {
        env: 'AutodeskProduction',
        getAccessToken: getForgeToken
    };
    fileName = name;
    var documentId = 'urn:' + urn;
    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized() {
    viewerApp = new Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication('forgeViewer');
    viewerApp.registerViewer(viewerApp.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D);
    viewerApp.loadDocument(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
    });
}
```

Then the viewer is being closed by this:

```
var viewer = viewerApp.getCurrentViewer();
viewer.tearDown();
viewerApp.finish();
viewerApp = null;
```

This closes the viewer on the screen; however, it does not remove the data created by the viewer.  A heap snapshot taken before a viewer is created contains 10.5MB of data, a heap snapshot taken after creating the viewer contains 66.1MB of data, and a third heap snapshot taken after the viewer has been removed contains 62.2MB of data.

How do I clean up the data created by launching a viewer?

Comment: I'm checking for more information, tried with `viewer.impl.unloadCurrentModel()` but got the same results

Comment: this will require further investigation, sorry about that

Comment: and would suggest using the latest version, 2.16, with improved memory handling

Comment: Will do, thank you

Comment: did some additional testing, the memory footprint after Viewer unload, if you look at the objects, is quite small. As mentioned, we did (and still doing)  improvements on memory handling.